# How to change the default MIB searching path?

Tags: c, snmp, net-snmp, mib

I have the following code to parse the mibs in a folder called mibp  .

```
#include <net-snmp/net-snmp-config.h>
#include <net-snmp/net-snmp-includes.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{

FILE *fp=NULL;
fp=fopen("/root/mib2.txt","w");
if (fp == NULL )
{
printf("error");;
exit(2);
}  

netsnmp_init_mib();

add_mibdir("/home/pradipta/snmp/share/snmp/mibp");
//netsnmp_set_mib_directory( "/home/pradipta/snmp/share/snmp/mibp" );

struct tree *node;
//node=read_all_mibs();
node=read_mib("/home/pradipta/snmp/share/snmp/mibp/EtherLike-MIB.txt");
print_subtree(fp,node,0);
}
```

when I am running this I error as follows

```
 MIB search path: /root/.snmp/mibs:/home/pradipta/snmp/share/snmp/mibs
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Cannot find module (IF-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Cannot find module (IP-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Cannot find module (TCP-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Cannot find module (UDP-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-VIEW-BASED-ACM-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-SMI): At line 6 in /home/pradipta/snmp/share/snmp/mibp/EtherLike-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 10 in /home/pradipta/snmp/share/snmp/mibp/EtherLike-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (IF-MIB): At line 12 in /home/pradipta/snmp/share/snmp/mibp/EtherLike-MIB.txt
Did not find 'mib-2' in module #-1 (/home/pradipta/snmp/share/snmp/mibp/EtherLike-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'transmission' in module #-1 (/home/pradipta/snmp/share/snmp/mibp/EtherLike-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'TruthValue' in module #-1 (/home/pradipta/snmp/share/snmp/mibp/EtherLike-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'ifIndex' in module #-1 (/home/pradipta/snmp/share/snmp/mibp/EtherLike-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'InterfaceIndex' in module #-1 (/home/pradipta/snmp/share/snmp/mibp/EtherLike-MIB.txt)
Unlinked OID in EtherLike-MIB: etherMIB ::= { mib-2 35 }
Undefined identifier: mib-2 near line 14 of /home/pradipta/snmp/share/snmp/mibp/EtherLike-MIB.txt
Unlinked OID in EtherLike-MIB: dot3 ::= { transmission 7 }
Undefined identifier: transmission near line 118 of /home/pradipta/snmp/share/snmp/mibp/EtherLike-MIB.txt
```

I have changed the folder name `mibs` to `mibp` and added as above in the code to test for the changing of mib search path working or not.it is giving me this error why.

what is the use of `netsnmp_init_mib();`

Also tell me

1. which function I will use to change the MIB searching directory.
2. what is the use of the function `netsnmp_set_mib_directory()`.
3. IF i want to add one MIB then can it possible to give the path of that MIB only or it is mandatory to include this in the path where all the MIBs are present previously as I am getting error when doing like this.
4. also what is the difference between  `read_all_mibs() and read_mib()`;

Kindly tell me some idea.

Comment: It seems that NetSNMP has trouble to find standard MIBs. Check the search path (1st line): `MIB search path: /root/.snmp/mibs:/home/pradipta/snmp/share/snmp/mibs`. Are there the default MIBs?

Answer (score 0):

It's trying to include the other MIBs that your MIB depends on. It's probably finding your specific MIB ok. Just add another `add_mibdir()` where ever your default MIBs are.

`add_mibdir("/usr/local/where/my/default/RFC/mibs/are");`

Comment: also another thing is that in the folder mibp all the RFC mibs are there previously as I have only renamed the default folder of mibs to mibp,so what is wrong here. kindly tell me about this.

Comment: Basically, just add the mibp directory similarly to how you added the `/home/pradipta/snmp/share/snmp/mibp`. Unless you're talking about the same directory. If so, they should be there. Make sure they're there.